# Spring & Hibernate: Unknown Column in 'field list' but column name is matching

Tags: java, spring-boot, entity

This is my first API with Spring Boot. I was able to make an entry into my database by performing a POST request in postman:

```
{
        "id":"1",
        "type":"postman",
        "cycleDate":"",
        "durationMiliseconds":"",
        "defects":"0"
}
```

Now, as I make the same request (id = 2), I get a 500 error, and the following from my API:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column
> 'cycle_date' in 'field list'

My code is as follows for this Entity:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Test
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
protected int id;

@Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
protected String type;

@Column(name = "cycle_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
protected Date cycleDate;

@Column(name = "duration_milliseconds")
protected int durationMilliseconds;

@Column(name = "defects")
protected int defects;

public Test()
{

}

public Test(int id, String type, Date cycleDate, int durationMilliseconds, int defects)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
    this.cycleDate = cycleDate;
    this.durationMilliseconds = durationMilliseconds;
    this.defects = defects;
}
```

Plus getters/setters.

I have confirmed that the column in my DB is named 'cycle_date' without any errors.

I do have another Entity which inherits from this one. The goal is for this entity to represent Api test results, while the superclass Entity represents just the overall test or test run and certain data associated with that. There will be other types of tests besides Api which will correlate to the superclass Test.

```
@Entity(name = "Api")
public class Api extends Test
{
@Column(name = "uri")
private String uri;

@Column(name = "request_type")
private String requestType;

@Column(name = "request_body")
private String requestBody;

@Column(name = "response_code")
private int responseCode;

@Column(name = "response_body")
private String responseBody;

public Api(int id, String type, Date cycleDate, int durationMilliseconds, int defects)
{
    super(id, type, cycleDate, durationMilliseconds, defects);
}
```

}

If I comment out this class, I receive the error: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: SQL String cannot be NULL

Is this an issue with my use of inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

For first error -

1. Try using sql logging to see what hibernate sql gets generated for create statement -

   hibernate.show_sql: true
2. You might want to look into hibernate naming strategy being used.

For second error - If you can post full stack trace that might help.

Personal suggestion: since "Post" verb is commonly used for creation of entity, id, should not be passed in request. Rather it should be part of response and location header.